# Как работает Gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Gunicorn запускает приложение flask один раз или каждый запрос запускает отдельное приложение на человека?

Comment: Этот же вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122807/how-gunicorn-and-shared-variables-work

Comment: Обычно один раз. Но вы можете отрегулировать количество запускаемых экземпляров (воркеров) и частоту перезапуска в настройках gunicorn

Comment: @andreymal А как быть с запланированными заданиями? они же получается будут выполнятся по нескольку раз?

Comment: @Андрей запланированные задания должны выполняться не в gunicorn, а в отдельном процессе (например celery-воркере)